# Consider the equation x2−2 = 0. Use Newton’s method to determine an approximation to the positive root starting with x0 = 1

Tags: python

Consider the equation x2−2 = 0. Use Newton’s method to determine an approximation to the positive root starting with x0 = 1.

I tried the python, but it is not corrected. Can you tell me where I got wrong

```
 def newton(p,dp,x0,tol = 1e-14,catch = 1000):
        x=x0
        r=-p(x)

        iter =0

        while abs(r) > tol and iter < catch:
                d = dp(x)
                x +=  r/d
                r = -p(x)
                iter += 1
        return x, iter

>>> from file import newton
>>> p = lambda x:x**-2
>>> dp = lambda x:2*x
>>> x0=1;tol = 1e-15;maxiter =10

>>> root = newton(p,dp,x0,tol,maxiter)
>>> print 'root = %.16f in %i iterations' % root
root = 1.0000000000000000 in 10 iterations
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
x0=1;tol = 1e-15;maxiter =10
```

to:

```
x0=1.0;tol = 1e-15;maxiter =10
```

Or better yet use different lines:

```
x0 = 1.0
tol = 1e-15 
maxiter = 10
```

Otherwise `x0` is treated as exclusively an integer instead of a float.